# call some method in background every 5 mins

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice, background-service

Hello I'm trying to sent from my app to server some string every 5 min in background service, but in my server I can see that it sends data every 3 sec. It's sure in bad logic, but I cannot see it. Could anyone give me help?
Thanks

```
public class MyClass extends IntentService{
public MyClass(){
    super("");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "The service has now started");
    setALarm();
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        sendLog();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logs Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is NOT avail!"+DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}

public void sendLog(){
    final String CLASS_NAME = "MujCLASSname";

    String LOG = "Network is avail!"+DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    Item item = new Item();
    if(!LOG.equals("")){
        item.setName(LOG);
        item.save().continueWith(new Continuation<IBMDataObject, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void then(Task<IBMDataObject> task) throws Exception {
                if (task.isCancelled()){
                    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Exception : Task " + task.toString() + " was cancelled.");
                }
                // Log error message, if the save task fails.
                else if (task.isFaulted()) {
                    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "Exception : " + task.getError().getMessage());
                }

                // If the result succeeds, load the list.
                else {
                    MainActivity ls = new MainActivity();
                    ls.listItems();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void setALarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            1000*60*5*2, alarmIntent);
}
```

}

```
    08-17 21:10:34.924  15574-15660/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:10:50.333  15574-16100/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:14:48.056  15574-18056/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:14:52.512  15574-18185/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:15:14.354  15574-18378/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:15:18.538  15574-18409/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:17:17.238  15574-19324/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:19:47.312  15574-20394/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:20:19.477  15574-20640/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:20:19.626  15574-20646/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:22:19.987  15574-22298/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:24:47.416  15574-23660/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
08-17 21:24:48.831  15574-23688/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.bluelist﹕ The service has now started
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
setInexactRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements;
>   for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at
>   the top of every hour.

replace alarmMgr.set by alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating

Comment: Thank you it works well. But can you look to my updated post? it sends doesnt match the time I set.